# MediaWiki 404 error for search results page

Tags: mediawiki

I just upgraded Mediawiki from 1.24 to 1.32 It's running PHP 7.0.33, MySQL 5.6.40 on a shared server from SiteGround.

When I use the built-in search box, most of the time it works fine. For example, if I search for "Restaurant", I'll get search results and the URL looks like this:

http://wiki.mydomain.com/index.php?search=restaurant&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go

But if I put in a search term where there exists a wiki page with the same name, I get a 404 error. For example, if I search for"Automobile", I get a 404 error and the URL looks like this:

http://wiki.mydomain.com/http://wiki.mydomain.com/index.php?title=Automobile

As you can see, it's listing my domain name twice.

It should return the page http://wiki.mydomain.com/index.php?title=Automobile - does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem by adding

```
$wgServer = "./";
```

to LocalSetting.php